# Issue with PolledProcessor on Spring cloud data flow

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm implememting a spring cloud data flow processor using PolledProcessor. I followed the example here https://spring.io/blog/2018/02/27/spring-cloud-stream-2-0-polled-consumers. Below is my code. I deployed a stream with a source piping to this processor (source | polled-processor) to scdf, and have the source published some messages. I confirm that the processor polls message from the scdf rabbitmq every second, but the `result` is always `false`. I went to the scdf rabbitmq console, I see those messages are all in the queue. So the processor is not polling the message although it keeps polling in the code. I also see there is no consumer for the queue. Looks like scdf did not bind this processor to the queue. Any idea why?

```
public interface PolledProcessor {
    @Input
    PollableMessageSource source();

    @Output
    MessageChannel dest();
}

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(PolledProcessor.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(PollableMessageSource source, MessageChannel dest) {
        return args -> {
            while (true) {
                boolean result = source.poll(dest::send);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

here is the status of the queue between the source and the processor

[image]

Comment: You need to edit the question to show the `application.yml/properties` and provide version information - but I won't be able to look at it until tomorrow. Comment here when you have done so, so I get a notification.

Comment: There is no application.yml/properties because the app does not use any properties. spring cloud data flow version is 2.6.1

Comment: There are no consumers in the screenshot. Are you looking at the right queue?

Comment: Yeah,  no consumer is my question . That is the queue that spring cloud data flow auto created between source and processor and it supposed to bind the processor as consumer to the queue

Comment: My mistake - polled consumers are short-lived and, generally, won't show up in the UI. I'll test and post back soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested a Spring Cloud Stream app with no problems:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Polled.class)
public class So69383266Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So69383266Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(PollableMessageSource source) {
        return args -> {
            while (true) {
                boolean result = source.poll(System.out::println);
                System.out.println(result);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        };
    }

}

interface Polled {

    @Input
    PollableMessageSource source();

}
```

```
false
GenericMessage [payload=byte[6], headers={...
true
false
```

I suggest you set a breakpoint in `AmqpMessageSource.doReceive()` to see what's going on.

**EDIT**

Here's how to check that the source is consuming from the correct queue:

```java
@Bean
public ApplicationRunner runner(PollableMessageSource source) {
    return args -> {
        while (true) {
            DirectFieldAccessor dfa = new DirectFieldAccessor(source);
            log.info(dfa.getPropertyValue("source.h.advised.targetSource.target.queue").toString());
            boolean result = source.poll(System.out::println);
            System.out.println(result);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: If I test with TestChannelBinder it worked fine. The issue only happens when I run this as a processor on spring cloud dataflow. I don't know if this is the reason. Will this work in spring cloud dataflow since this method is for spring cloud stream?

Comment: Yes; dataflow is "just" an orchestrator for spring cloud stream apps. Try running it locally with the rabbit binder. I am not a dataflow expert, but you should show your stream definition and deployment properties.

Comment: here is my stream definition `source | polled-processor`. `source` is a dataflow source app that publish messages. `polled-processor` is this processor. I'm not sure how to test with a rabbit binder. Do you mean test this standalone app with a rabbitmq? If I test this app in my local spring cloud dataflow it has the same issue.

Comment: What about deployment properties? Yes; run it as a stand-alone SCSt app in a debugger.

Comment: For this specific app, there is no properties

Comment: How to bind a rabbitmq to the app? I asked this question in another post and answer I got was using TestChannelBinder

Comment: Add `<artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>` to the pom and remove the test binder.

Comment: I tested the standalone app with a local rabbitmq server and it worked. It automatically created a queue on startup, and I posted a message to that queue and it was received by the `poll` method. It just does not work when I deploy to spring cloud dataflow

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me; unfortunately, I don't see any useful DEBUG logging to figure out what's wrong. I added some code to show how to verify that it is consuming from th correct queue.

Comment: Thanks for the code. It shows that the queue it is consuming is a wrong one `source.anonymous.XXX` which is also generated by the processor on startup. It is supposed to bind to the queue that scdf created between source and processor. Any idea why?

Comment: That means the consumer is anonymous - which means there is no binding `group` property - normally SCDF puts each binding in a group - that's why I wanted you to show the complete stream definition (not just the `source | polled-processor` snippet. I believe SCDF uses `input` and `output` for its binding names (at least by default) - try changing `source()` to `input()`. Or `@Input("input")`. I am not familiar enough with SCDF to know how to tell it to use custom binding names (if you can).

Comment: That fixed the issue. Thank you for the help!